# How do I read the contents of a specific textview in a ListView without using rowID or OnClickEvent?

Tags: android

My app is properly populating a ListView. I need to find out the contents of a specific TextView when the user taps on the row. I don't need the RowID, and due to how the app works, I can't use OnClickEvent.

How can I get the currently displayed contents of the TextView on the tapped row?

EDIT:
Below is how I implemented the suggestion to use `onItemClick`. My layout uses a FrameLayout to allow for tapping on the right or left side of a row. Depending on the side tapped, it triggers a different activity. Both activities need the contents of the TextView called `bonusListCode`, which is what I'm trying to fetch.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Entered onItemClickListener");
            Intent nextActivity = new Intent(bonusListing.this, bonusListing.class);
            startActivity(nextActivity);
        }
```

When I tap on my cell, it goes to the appropriate activity, but I don't see the log entry that the above code should trigger, so it isn't being triggered. What am I doing wrong in the `onItemClickListener`?

EDIT 2: I am seeing some older posts that indicated it might be easier to pull this from my cursor since I'm using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Below is mine:

```
// Populate the ListView w/ all rows
        Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataAllBonuses();
        listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bonus_list_row_item, data,
                new String[] {"sCode", "sName", "sCategory", "sCity", "sState"},
                new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName, R.id.bonusListCategory, R.id.bonusListCity, R.id.bonusListState}, 0));
```

Edit 3: Additional code per request. 
Here is my bonusListing.java file, which is how I'm populating the ListView.

```
public class bonusListing extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "bonusListing"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    UserDataDBHelper userDBHelper;
    AppDataDBHelper appDBHelper;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bonus_listing);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(tohPreferences,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvBonusData);

        // Handle the appData DB.
        appDBHelper = new AppDataDBHelper(this);

        try {
            Log.e(TAG,"Calling createDatabase");
            appDBHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to CREATE DATABASE");
        }

        // Populate the ListView w/ all rows
        Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataAllBonuses();
        listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bonus_list_row_item, data,
                new String[] {"sCode", "sName", "sCategory", "sCity", "sState"},
                new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName, R.id.bonusListCategory, R.id.bonusListCity, R.id.bonusListState}, 0));

        // Print to Log the DB headers
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(appDBHelper.getWritableDatabase());


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Entered onItemClickListener");
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(bonusListing.this, bonusListing.class);
                startActivity(nextActivity);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Log.e(TAG,"action_setting");
                startActivity(new Intent(this, appSettings.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.action_trophyMode:
                Log.e(TAG,"action_trophyMode");
                startActivity(new Intent(this, trophyMode.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.action_filter:
                Log.e(TAG,"action_filter");
                // Populate the ListView w/ filtered data
                ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvBonusData);
                Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataFilteredBonuses();
                listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bonus_list_row_item, data,
                        new String[] {"sCode", "sName", "sCategory", "sCity", "sState"},
                        new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName, R.id.bonusListCategory, R.id.bonusListCity, R.id.bonusListState}, 0));
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public int getIdFromClassName(String className){
        String query = "SELECT rowid" +
                " FROM " + CLASSES_TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + CLASSES_COLUMN_NAME + " = ?;";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, query, new String[]{ className });
    }

    public void goToAppSettings (View View) {
        Log.e(TAG,"goToAppSettings");
        Intent goToAppSettings = new Intent(this,appSettings.class);
        startActivity(goToAppSettings);
    }

    public void goToTrophyMode (View View) {
        Log.e(TAG,"goToTrophyMode");
        Intent goToTrophyMode = new Intent(this,trophyMode.class);
        startActivity(goToTrophyMode);
    }

    public void goToCaptureBonus (View View) {
        String tappedBonus = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)).getText().toString();
        Log.e(TAG,"goToCaptureBonus, tapped bonus = " + tappedBonus);
        Intent goToCaptureBonus = new Intent(this,captureBonus.class);
        goToCaptureBonus.putExtra("codeTapped",tappedBonus);
        startActivity(goToCaptureBonus);
    }

    public void goToBonusDetail (View View) {
        String tappedBonus = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)).getText().toString();

        Log.e(TAG,"goToBonusDetail, tapped bonus = " + tappedBonus);
        Intent goToBonusDetail = new Intent(this,bonusDetail.class);
        goToBonusDetail.putExtra("codeTapped",tappedBonus);
        startActivity(goToBonusDetail);
    }
}
```

EDIT 4: Layout file. Here is my bonus_list_row_item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListImage"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mainImageDescription"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image_taken" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
            android:text="@string/valueCategory" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListCategory"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusListCode"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusCode" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusListCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusCity"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusListState"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusState"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftSideRowTapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:onClick="goToBonusDetail"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightSideRowTapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.0"
            android:onClick="goToCaptureBonus"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and in case it is useful, here is the activity_bonus_listing.xml as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvBonusData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement **OnClickEvent** instead impelement **OnItemClickListener** like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(SuggestionActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Comment: My apologies for the slow response, I had an unexpected family emergency pop up. I tried using that in my code, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have updated my question with more details. Would you mind taking a look and providing me some guidance?

Comment: can you please provide all code of your activity. It'll be easier to resolve your issue.

Comment: put this in `onItemCick` so we know if click event is working properly. If it is working properly we'll proceed and extract data on click. Let me know if its printing listview position correctly.`Toast.makeText(bonusListing.this, "You clicked "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: I made my `onItemClick` look like, `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Entered onItemClickListener");
                Toast.makeText(bonusListing.this, "You clicked "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });` but it doesn't seem to have done anything. I got no notice on screen nor anything in the log.

Comment: can you post your layout because everything seems correct. May be your listview is overlapped with some other layout.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: I'll fix it for you if you by any chance put your project on git. That'll be easy to find problem.

Comment: I can do that. Here you go: https://github.com/DJFriar/aTourofHonor.git

Comment: you forgot to upload file version.properties for gradle.build. java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not read version.properties

Comment: I managed to resolve that issue. but I'm unable to fetch records from database on bonusDetails acitivity. Could you tell me how you are inserting records in database?

Comment: The appdata.db file should be in app/src/main/assets. It is created externally and then just added to the project. The app doesn’t modify the DB itself.

Comment: the one in the GitHub project has valid data within it.

Comment: Anything else I can do to help you help me?